# running a mysql query containing division in laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel-5

I want to run this mysql query in Laravel 5 using the DB query :

```
// SELECT *, rating/number as total FROM `courses` order by total DESC;
```

This is what I tried :

```
$query   = \DB::table('courses')->select('*');
$courses = $query->addSelect('rating/number as total')
                 ->orderBY('total DESC')
                 ->get();
```

but, rating/number is considered as a table column . The same thing happens when I tried it inside parenthesis (rating/number).
Any help?

Comment: The same thing happens when I tried it inside parenthesis (rating/number). it's mentioned above

Comment: Oh, sorry, not sure how I managed to overlook that.

Comment: Raw expressions? http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#raw-expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$courses = \DB::table('courses')
              ->selectRaw('*, rating/number as total')
              ->orderBY('total', 'DESC')
              ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use [Raw Expressions](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#raw-expressions) for it? Maybe something like this:

```
$courses = \DB::table('courses')
                 ->select(DB::raw('*, (rating / number) as total'))
                 ->orderBy('total DESC')
                 ->get();
```